# I am trying to send email from abc company address to gmail or any other mail server , but getting connection time out

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, jakarta-mail

*I have created a java program to send email from webmail to gmail , but for some reason im
getting connection time out and `com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException`: Couldn't connect to
host.*
**Here is my code** :

```
 String from = "asg@abc.com";
 String pass ="***";
 String to = "ag@gmail.com";
 String host = "smtp.webmail.abc.com";
 Properties properties = System.getProperties();
 properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
 properties.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
 properties.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
 properties.put("mail.smtp.password", pass);
 properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
 properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

 try{
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
    message.setText("This is actual message");
    Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect(host, from, pass);
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
    transport.close();
    System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
   }catch (MessagingException mex) {
    mex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

Comment: Is SMTP running over TLS on port 465 of smtp.webmail.abc.com? Are you sure? Couldn't connect to host would seem to indicate smtp.webmail.abc.com doesn't exist.

Comment: I had tried for port 587 as well but it didn't work. I was getting the same error.

Comment: Doing a MX resolve on abc.com gives `abc.com mail exchanger = 10 abc-com.mail.protection.outlook.com.` where did you get "smtp.webmail.abc.com"?

Comment: it worked after i change it to smtp.webmail.com but on browser it showing email sent successfully but no mail has been received and on console showing below error:
`com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.webmail.com, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Comment: I don't know why you claim "it worked". Because you still get the same "Couldn't connect to host".